# Graphicx package not inserting/scaling new images properly

Tags: graphics

The following code puts the figure at the very end of my paper, after the references and the image is really small in the bottom left corner on it's own page.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \includegraphics[width = 20cm]{img011class.pdf}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). With those clues, who knows! That code fragment alone does not show any problem.  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem,  using as images that of the `mwe` package ( `example-image`, for instance) so everybody will be able to reproduce exactly the problem without having to guess what are you doing really.

Comment: Some guesses: if your pages are less than 20cm wide then LaTeX cannot fit the graphic on the page where you put the command, and it is moved to the end instead. Try `width=\textwidth` instead. For the bottom left corner issue: maybe the pdf with the image (`img011class.pdf`) is a big pdf that is mostly empty with the graphic in the corner. When you include such a file then the whitespace is included as well. Open the file in a pdf viewer to see if this is the case, and try to reduce the whitespace in the program that you used to create this pdf.

Comment: @Ingmar what do you mean by your comment about the option? I would have commented that the OP is missing `p` and the float is less likely to go to the end if it was `[htbp]` In particular you should never use `h` on its own (that usually generates a warning)

Comment: As a check use `\fbox{\includegraphics{img011class.pdf}}` so you get a box showing the image extent, is the pdf just the image you want or is it a complete page with a lot of white space?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are right, of course, p is missing. I still think the width is potentially excessive.

Comment: @Ingmar you could delete your first comment:-) yes the width actually doesn't affect placement but making it that wide probably makes it tall as well in which case if it is taller than the text area it won't get placed.